# calling aws lamdba directly by rest api without api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In the this blog(https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb) I see that with only serverless.yaml :

```
# serverless.yml

service: serverless-flask

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

and app.py:

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():u
    return "Hello World!"
```

How is possible to call lambda direct from the internet. Which service/component of aws getting this URL and is it permanent. Can URL can be customized without API gateway? is it also possible to give this URL to customers for use as an API?

Answer (score 2):

A "serverless" (i.e. [serverless.com](https://www.serverless.com/)) function that has `http` `events` is creating an API gateway for you. The requests to the API Gateway endpoint will be sent to the lambda. Because you are using the `{proxy+}` option it will basically route everything to the function and expect the function to figure out what the request means.

If you want to call the function directly from the internet you can, but you probably shouldn't. All AWS APIs are just HTTPs calls. Calling them from the internet would require having credentials to do so, and signing the request appropriately. If you do really want to call it directly from the internet you might consider using Cognito. You can get temporary credentials via a Cognito identity, and you can invoke the lambda via an SDK to have the signing handled for you.

Comment: Can call  AWS lambda directly using rest API without using any other AWS service?

Comment: Not without ANY. You at least need credentials, so an IAM user, or some other means of getting those credentials. You can call invoke the lambda by calling the Invoke API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html).